# How to display a Gaussian High Pass kernel as Bitmap?

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, gaussian

How can I convert a [Gaussian High Pass kernel](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/456916/Homomorphic_Filter-noexe.zip) into a Bitmap image for display purposes?

I have tried the following functions:

1. *Double to Integer*:

   ```
   public static Bitmap ToBitmap(Array2d<double> image, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
   {
       Array2d<double> imageCopy = image.Copy();

       int Width = imageCopy.Width;
       int Height = imageCopy.Height;

       Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height, pixelFormat);

       for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
       {
           for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
           {
               double d = imageCopy[x, y];

               int iii = Convert.ToInt32(d*255.0);

               Color clr = Color.FromArgb(iii, iii, iii);

               bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, clr);
           }
       }

       return bitmap;
   }
   ```
2. *Log stretch*:

   ```
   public static Array2d<double> Stretch(Array2d<double> data)
   {
       int Width = data.Width;
       int Height = data.Height;

       Array2d<double> array2d = new Array2d<double>(Width, Height);

       for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < Height; j++)
           {
               array2d[i, j] = Math.Log(data[i, j] + 1);
           }
       }

       return array2d;
   }
   ```

Neither of them seems to be working as they are giving the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Drawing.dll
>
> Additional information: Value of '133028503' is not valid for 'red'.
>   'red' should be greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to
>   255.

The following in the sample data from the Gaussian kernel:

[image]

Some values are too low and some are too high to be converted to an Integer in the range of 0-255.

Comment: @MickyD, `Some values are too low and some are too high to be converted to an Integer in the range of 0-255.` So, they are giving an exception.

Comment: 'Gaussian' it is. So you need to normalize the data. You could try to use `Color clr = Color.FromArgb(int);` for a wider range and a colorful result, depending on the data.. ;-)

Comment: @TaW, Normalization is giving small values like **0.004897**. So, as a result a black output.

Comment: A Gaussian kernel is not supposed to have negative values. In any case, you have shared code here earlier where you scale input values to the output range. Did you try using that? The input has a large range, the output needs to be in the range 0-255, as indicated by the error message.

Comment: You need to do a pass over your data first and determine min/max values, then scale by that range and transpose to make it positive. If you are doing normalization to [0-255], some of the pixels will be black, yes. 

Perhaps you should add an example image of the desired visualization of such a kernel to your question. If we know what you expect it to look like, then we can help with the technical conversion to bitmap.

Comment: [Pyramid (image processing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)).  [Kernel (image processing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing))